# Stubbing with sinon but stub not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

How to stub `_http_outgoing.js`?
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js

I have `var anOutgoingMessage = <OutgoingMessage>{};`  which I pass into my API call `Get(anIncomingMessage,anOutcomingMessage)` in that `Get` there is a `anOutcomingMessage.end(data)`.

In my test I want to confirm `end` is called with the expected data.

I've tried both

1. `const outgoingMessageSpy = sinon.stub(OutgoingMessage.prototype,"end");`

and

2. `const outgoingMessageSpy = sinon.stub(anOutgoingMessage,"end");`

then I

`expect(outgoingMessageSpy.called).to.be.true()`

For 1) `outgoingMessageSpy.called` is just false. For 2) I get `Cannot stub non-existent property end`

`end` is defined in _http_outgoing.js as `OutgoingMessage.prototype.end = function end(chunk, encoding, callback) {` as per link above.

What would be the right way to stub this message and confirm end is called with the parameter I expect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`var anOutgoingMessage = <OutgoingMessage>{};` was the issue!
it's got to be `var anOutgoingMessage = new OutgoingMessage();`. Of course there is no `end` otherwise in `{}`.
Drove me nuts